# Is there a Rails pattern for giving different kinds of users different home pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My initial thought is to just have a `home_page` attribute on the `User` model and then do a `redirect_to` after authentication. Is it as simple as that, or is there a better way?

As background, here are some of the use cases:

One user can be an admin, and can impersonate other users on the site for support purposes. Our admins do this so that they can "see" what the customer is seeing. When logging in, an admin will be directed to a page that shows current usage statistics as well as any errors that are occurring across the application.

Another type of user is a collaborator from a partner marketplace. Let's say that company is called Amazing. A manager from Amazing can log in and see all of the users that are selling products on the Amazing marketplace, yet he doesn't have the same access as an Admin. I want to redirect this user to a page that shows all of the sellers on the Amazing marketplace.

A standard customer will be directed to a dashboard page that will help them manage advertisements on a marketplace.

Comment: It would help to know what would be different about the home pages?  Like totally different template? Different URL?

Comment: And more importantly what would be different about the users? Unless it need to be cusomized per user storing it on column on the users table seems like a very wasteful and brittle solution. Do you really want to have to update thousands of rows just because a URL changes?

Comment: I've always envisioned this feature for my forum. There is no reason a user shouldn't be able to choose which page of the site loads when they visit the home URL if they are logged in. I figure I'd add it as a setting attribute for the user just as normal, and redirect to it if it exists. It should be that easy.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have added use cases. I'd like to use paths, but I  don't know how I redirect to a path that is a string (like dashboard_path) coming from a model, without using an eval like: eval('redirect_to dashboard_path')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate home page for user if using [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise). On an old project I did something like this, code is not so clean, but you can get an idea:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

  devise_for :admins,
             :frontend_operators,
             :backend_operators,
             class_name: 'User',
             path: '',
             controllers: {sessions: 'frontend/auth/sessions',
                           confirmations: 'frontend/auth/confirmations',
                           unlocks: 'frontend/auth/unlocks',
                           passwords: 'frontend/auth/passwords',
                           registrations: 'frontend/auth/registrations'},
             path_names: {sign_in: 'login',
                          sign_out: 'logout',
                          password: 'secret',
                          confirmation: 'verification',
                          sign_up: 'register',
                          edit: 'profile/edit'}
...

  authenticated :backend_operator do
    get :backend_operator_root, action: :index, controller: "backend/home"
  end
  authenticated :frontend_operator do
    get :frontend_operator_root, action: :index, controller: "frontend/home"
  end
  authenticated :admin do
    get :admin_root, action: :index, controller: "backend/home"
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  devise_group :user, contains: [:backend_operator, :frontend_operator, :admin]

  [:backend_operator, :frontend_operator, :admin].each do |model|

    define_method("decorated_current_#{model}") { send("current_#{model}").decorate }
    helper_method "decorated_current_#{model}".to_sym
  end

  before_action :set_root, unless: :root_present?

  protected

  def set_root
    Rails.application.config.root_url = root_url
  end
end
```